# Random number generator javascript. How can I prevent it generating a new number on refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, random, refresh, generator

Ok I got this code:

```
<font face="Arial" size="2">Your random number:</font></b><br></br>
<span class="xr_tl Normal_text" style=" top: 0px;
                                        font-family:Impact;
                                        font-size:20px;
                                        color:#c04e51;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(Math.floor(Math.random()*999999));
    </script>
</span>
```

It generates a random number when you visit the page and works fine but I need it to generate a random number just once. That means when you click refresh, there is no new random number generated and the previously generated number just stays there. How can I do this? I assume it can be done by sending a cookie but I can't figure it out.

Comment: write() this instead: localStorage.rnd || (localStorage.rnd=Math.floor(Math.random()*999999))

Comment: you cannot figure cookies out? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: why do you want to do this though? Because eventually after time you will generate the same number for a user.

Comment: @Logan http://w3fools.com

Comment: @bjb568 I am well aware that w3schools isn't the gratest resource, but it is a starting point and does not invalidate the code in the supplied webpage.

Comment: @Logan It's a never point.

Comment: @bjb568 So what website should we look at for learning web technologies?

Comment: @Logan Microsoft De… Nope. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47049/discussion-between-logan-murphy-and-bjb568)

Answer (score 1):

You have to store that number somewhere and then use it. For example in a cookie. Here are some functions to set, get and unset a cookie. I think using cookies is better then localstorage because you choose how long they stay valid.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't help much.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: cookies also slow down your site and leave their values in logs along the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = localStorage.getItem('num') || Math.floor(Math.random()*999999);
localStorage.setItem('num',num);
document.write(num);
```

Just stick it in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localStorage API to store information that will remain after the page is closed or refreshed.

```
var res = localStorage.getItem('randomNumber');
if(res == null){
    res  = Math.floor(Math.random()*999999)
    localStorage.setItem('randomNumber', res);
}

document.write(res);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CFKSG/2/)